# inclusion of von Neumann algebras with expectation

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $N\subset M$ be any inclusion of $\sigma$-finite von Neumann algebras with expectation $E_N： M\rightarrow N$.

If $A\subset N\subset M$ is an abelian von Neumann subalgerba with expectation that is maximal abelian in $M$. Can we find a faithful normal state $\omega$ on $M$ such that $\omega\circ E_N=\omega$ and $A\subset N_{\omega}$, where $N_{\omega}$ is the centralizer of $N$.

Comment: Are you assuming that the expectation is normal? Faithful?

Comment: Yes, it is normal and faithful

Comment: Then you take a normal faithful state $\omega'$ on $N$, and define $\omega=\omega'\circ E_N$. The masa will always be in the centralizer because it is abelian.

Comment: Thanks very much！

Comment: When veryfing $A\subset N_{\omega}$, I met with troubles. We need to prove that for any $x\in A$, we have  $x\in  N_{\omega}$.  As $x\omega (y)=\omega (yx), \omega x(y)=\omega (xy)$ for all $y\in N$.  $A$ is abelian ,we cannot conclude that $xy=yx$ for all $y\in N$.

Comment: I don't have a general answer, but I typed what I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there exists a faithful normal conditional expectation $E_A$, take a faithful normal state $\omega''$ on $A$ and define $\omega'=\omega''\circ E_A$. Then put  $\omega=\omega'\circ E_N$.

Now if $x\in A$, $y\in N$,
$$
\omega(xy)=\omega(E_A(xy))=\omega(xE_A(y))=\omega(E_A(y)x)=\omega(E_A(yx))=\omega(yx).
$$

Comment: I feel a little confused the statment "$A\subset N\subset M$ is an abelian von Neumann subalgerba with expectation". Accoding to this,  can we conclude that there must exist a faithful normal conditional expectation $E_A:N\rightarrow A$ and a faithful normal conditional expectation $E_A:M\rightarrow A$ ?

Comment: I don't know. That statement means nothing to me. That's why I wrote "if" in my answer.

Comment: The statement is from the paper "structure of bicentralizer algebras and inclusions of type III", which is a joint work of  Ando, Haagerup, Houdayer and Marrakchi.